# Complexity of a reaching-a-node 2 player graph game

Tags: time-complexity, graph-algorithm, game-theory

The game:

- there is an undirected simple graph with some special, winning nodes, and 2 players, who take turns
- player one (Seeker) moves on the graph (sits on a node, and moves along an edge), and tries to reach a winning node. If she can, she wins.
- player two (Eraser) can turn the winning nodes into regular nodes. She wins, if the other player can't win, that is, she erased all the winning nodes into regular ones.

I am interested about this game.

E.g. if this game "can be solved" in polynomial or even in NP or coNP time, that is, whether it is possible to decide who has a winning strategy.
Or whether this game is in the literature, and is known to be easy or hard, possibly in a different form.

Thank you!

edit:

- I gave the players names according to their roles.
- P1's position is part of the initial setup

Comment: Player one - start on a winning node, done. So the starting position of player 1 should be part of the game instance. Does player 2 have a position and have to move as well? Otherwise the strategy of p2 will be trivial, nuke one of the nodes that's closest to p1. If p1 is too far, p2 wins, otherwise p1 wins.

Comment: This seems related to the "cops and robbers" group of graph theory problems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cop-win_graph

Comment: "Otherwise the strategy of p2 will be trivial, nuke one of the nodes that's closest to p1." 

That's not working even on trees. Consider the following graph:
(W) ---- ( ) ---- (p1) ----- ( ) ----- (Q) 
where W is a winning node, and there are 3 additional winning nodes attached to Q. In this case p2 can win, but only if she destroys a winning node next to Q, and not the closest winning node.